# Makefile include header

Tags: c, makefile

I am new to Linux programming I tried to compile a simple test construction. But I'm getting an error when compiling. Adding inc.c as well (in the app: line) doesn't work. How should I include the file correct?

Makefile:

```
app: main.c inc.h
    cc -o app main.c
```

Terminal:

```
make
cc -o app main.c
/tmp/ccGgdRNy.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `test'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [app] Error 1
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "inc.h"

int main()
{
    printf("Kijken of deze **** werkt:\n");
    test();

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

inc.h

```
#ifndef INCLUDE_H

#define INCLUDE_H

void test();

#endif
```

inc.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test()
{
    printf("Blijkbaar wel!");
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You must link against the compilation unit `inc.o` which you obtain by compiling `inc.c`.

In general that means that you must supply all object files that contain functions that are used in `main.c` (transitively). You can compile these with implicit rules of `make`, no need to specify extra rules.

You could say:

```
app: main.c inc.o inc.h
    cc -o app inc.o main.c
```

And `make` will know on its own how to compile `inc.o` from `inc.c` although it will *not* take `inc.h` into account when determining whether `inc.o` must be rebuilt. For that you *would* have to specify your own rules.

Answer (score 4):

you didn't compile the inc.c file

```
app: main.c inc.h
    cc -o app main.c inc.c
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to compile `inc.c` as well. A suitable approach (better scalable to larger applications) would be to split the Makefile up into different targets. The idea is: one target for every object file, then one target for the final binary. For compiling the object files, use the `-c` argument.

```
app: main.o inc.o
    cc -o app main.o inc.o

main.o: main.c inc.h
    cc -c main.c

inc.o: inc.c inc.h
    cc -c inc.c
```

Comment: why do you put header file in `cc -c main.c inc.h` and `cc -c inc.c inc.h`?