# How to add headers to a Makefile?

Tags: c, makefile

I have the following `Makefile`. **How to add also some header files** that I have in the project folder (e.g. `header1.h` with its relative `header1.c`) ?

```
CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -O3
CFILES := $(shell ls *.c)
PROGS := $(CFILES:%.c=%)

all: $(PROGS)

.PHONY: all clean
clean:
    rm -f *~ $(PROGS)
```

Even adding them one by one would be ok (no need to use the wildcard).

I suppose I should edit the following line:

```
CFILES := $(shell ls *.c)
```

But **how**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Makefile include header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15440183/makefile-include-header)

Comment: .h files are not very useful as a wildcard in a makefile. They're more useful as manual dependencies

Comment: Why do you want headers in makefile?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I edited the OP, I don't need to use the wildcard! I just need gcc to get the correct dependencies

Comment: Notice that folders are GUI artefacts. Your system has [directories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_(computing)) and most of them do not appear as folders in your GUI desktop

Comment: You don't provide headers to `gcc` but instead the location where it will look for headers. This is done with the `-I` command line parameter. So add to your CFLAGS something like this : `-I "path/to/headers"`

Answer (score 4):

First, don't use `$(shell ls *.c)` but better `$(wildcard *.c)`. Please take time to read the [documentation of GNU `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html)

Then, you usually don't want headers in `Makefile`-s, you want *dependencies* on headers.

For example, if *you* know that `foo.o` needs both `foo.c` and `header.h` (because you have some `#include "header.h"` in your `foo.c`) you would add a dependency like

```
foo.o: foo.c header.h
```

in your `Makefile`... See also [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16751650/841108).

There is some way to automate such dependencies, using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) options; read about [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html), notably [preprocessor options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) like `-M`

<sup>(details depend upon your project and coding conventions)</sup>

For a simple project of a few dozen of files totalizing a few thousand lines, you should first write your `Makefile` explicitly, with the dependencies. Later you might automatize that (but in simple projects that is not worth the trouble).

In some cases, a header file `*.h` or a C file `*.c` is *generated* by some utility (e.g. [swig](http://swig.org/), [bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/), ... or your own script or program). Then you add appropriate specific rules in your `Makefile`.

You might use `make --trace` or [`remake`](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) with `-x` to debug your `Makefile`.

Look for inspiration into the [source code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code) of some existing [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) project (e.g. on [github](http://github.com/)).